# How to change spark config in Python

Tags: pyspark

Below is my python code

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('CD6').config('spark.ui.port','9999').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

I would like to amend following properties to false in the spark config.

How to change them using spark session command?

```
spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=false
spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false
```

I tried adding properties to .config; but it errors out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set spark config properties like so :

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.<name-of-property>", <value>)
```

in your case, it would be :

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc",False)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", False)
```